# how to convert objectHTML into html

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch-2

i have create an image object in javascript as follows

```
 var imgVal = new Image();
     imgVal.src= 'resources/img/def.png';
```

now I want to have some function which converts above `imgVal` object into `html` i.e.

```
<img scr="resources/img/def.png" />
```

i am using `sencha touch`so if is there any existing function available then please do tell me

following is the template

```
itemTpl:['<table border=0>',
                        '<tr><td  rowspan="2"><div id="ca-img-frame">{contact_image}</div></td><td>{contact_name}</td></tr>',
                        '<tr><td>{contact_number}</td></tr>',
                    '</table>'
                    ]
```

now i want to add `img` tag where `{contact_image}` is specified , as this table is a list item of listview id will be repeated in each item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, here is my answer

You have an image object

```
var imgVal = new Image();
imgVal.src= 'resources/img/def.png';
```

You need to get the HTML out of it, so

```
var div = document.createElement();
div.appendChild(imgVal);
console.log(div.innerHTML);
div = null;
```

See the console for what you wanted. see this http://jsfiddle.net/aAzdz/

Answer (score 1):

Use [**outerHTML**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.outerHTML) property of HTML.Do like

```
console.log(imgVal.outerHTML)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [**`.appendChild()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild) to the add it to their repective parent.

```
var imgVal = new Image();
imgVal.src= 'resources/img/def.png';
document.getElementById('idOfParent').appendChild(imgVal);
```

check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kDM2T/)

Comment: i dont have a provision here to get the id of a tag and insert because i have been  replacing img html with the template attribute {img_val} in sencha touch

Comment: @Hunt I can't get you.  Its ok, there is no need of `id`, you can even className or tagName(`getElementsByTagName`).

Comment: i short my chunk of html is created after that img tag is created so there is no way to get the id of any div

Comment: I haven't used in `sencha touch` but this is how you have to do in JS.

Comment: @Hunt where you want to add this image in HTML?  for example you want to append, but it would be helpful if you specify the respective tagName or..

Comment: @Hunt `document.getElementById('ca-img-frame').appendChild(imgVal);` is this didn't worked?